# date: invalid date trying to set linux date in specific format

Tags: linux, time, date

i try to set linux date & time in specific format but it keep giving me error
Example :

```
date "+%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -d "19-01-2017 00:05:01"
or 
date +"%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -d "19-01-2017 00:05:01"
```

keep giving me this error :

```
date: invalid date ‘19-01-2017 00:05:01’
```

Comment: I always just do MMDDhhmm, provided i don't need to change the existing year.  So for July 4 at 2:34pm you would do `date 07041434`.  If you wanted to set the year say to 1969, then it would be `date 070414341969`

Comment: if you do `man date` you will see that format defined such as `[MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]`  The [ ] means optional.  So if you did just `date 1434` then you would be trying to set the month and day not the hour and minute.  So if your date command requires MMDDhhmm then to simply set the time you **always** have to give 2-digit month and 2-digit day first before the 2-digit hour and 2-digit minute.

Answer (score 5):

The issue looks like to be your "date string", i.e. `"19-01-2017 00:05:01"`.

From the man page:

```
The  --date=STRING  is  a  mostly  free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or
       "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day,
       time  zone,  day  of  week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.
```

Now, "a mostly free format human readable date" is a bit vague, and looks like `19-01-2017` is **not** readable. Probably because it might be unparseable in cases like `02-03-2019` (is it March, 02 or February, 03?).

Try changing it to ISO format:

```
$> date "+%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -d "2017-01-19 00:05:01"
19-01-2017 00:05:01
```

o use a format like the example found in the man page:

```
$> date "+%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -d "19 Jan 2017 00:05:01"
19-01-2017 00:05:01
```

Comment: The [info pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html) (as recommended by the brief entry in the manpage) can expand on that "probably": when the month is a number, the date will be interpreted as either "year-month-day", or the US-style "month/day(/optional year)".

Comment: Thank you. I used this to set date ubuntu 18 $> date "+%d-%m-%C%y %H:%M:%S" -s "2021-06-03 04:38:01"